# Recorre listview y sumar datos de edittext

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que consume servicios web (*Web Services*), ya está avanzada y ahora estoy llenando un `ListView` por medio de un adaptador personalizado un detalle el cual trae información como el saldo y saldo vencido, y un `EditText` en cual van a digital cuánto se abonó a cada nota que tenga ese cliente.

Pero me encuentro en el detalle, que tengo un botón que cuando se de clic deberá de recorrer cada ítem de mi lista y revisará los `EditText` y si tiene algún dato lo sumará y el total será enviado por otro método vía servicios web, pero la verdad no sé cómo hacer esa operación, ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Por cierto uso el `Asynctask` para el llamado de los *Web Services*.

Este es mi código donde mando a llamar mi detalle y donde se ejecutará el botón

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent1=getIntent();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle__cliente);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    O_Cliente=(CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor) intent.getSerializableExtra("O_Cliente");
    setTitle(O_Cliente.getClienteDescripcion());
    //codigo listview
    list=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listDeta);
    AsyncCallWSDetalle task = new AsyncCallWSDetalle();
    //Call execute
    task.execute();

    //codigo proceso de pago
    Button pagar = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnpago);
    pagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            AsyncGrabarCXCP task = new AsyncGrabarCXCP();
            //Call execute

            list=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listDeta);

            for(int i=0;i<list.getCount();i++){
                View view=list.getChildAt(i);

                EditText edt_abono = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono);

                //DetalleCxP R_DetalleCxP = (DetalleCxP)((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtFolio)).getTag();

                String string=edt_abono.getText().toString();

                String string=editText.getText().toString();
                if(!string.equals(""))
                    total+=Double.parseDouble(string);
            }

            task.execute();
        }
    });
}

private class AsyncCallWSDetalle extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList, ArrayList> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params){
        DetalleArrayList=webService.DetalleCxP(O_Cliente.getCliente());
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    //Make Progress Bar visible
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        dialog=new ProgressDialog(Detalle_Cliente.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Cargando Detalle...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(ArrayList... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    //Once WebService returns response
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList) {
        super.onPostExecute(arrayList);
        if(DetalleArrayList.size()!=0){
            dialog.dismiss();

            adaptador= new MyArrayAdapter(Detalle_Cliente.this, DetalleArrayList);///* no se usa your_array_list

            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listDeta);
            listView.setAdapter(adaptador);
        }else{
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}

public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DetalleCxP> {

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DetalleCxP> ArrayClientes) {
        super(context, 0, ArrayClientes);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        DetalleCxP O_DetalleCxP = getItem(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_detalle, parent, false);
        }

        //Obteniendo instancias de los text views
        TextView fecha = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFecha);
        TextView folio = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFolio);
        TextView vencido = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvencido);
        TextView saldo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttotal);
        // EditText opcionOtros = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono);

        DecimalFormat numberFormat  = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        fecha.setText(dateFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getFecha()));

        folio.setText(O_DetalleCxP.getFolio());
        folio.setTag(O_DetalleCxP);

        vencido.setText(numberFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getSaldoVencido()));
        saldo.setText(numberFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getSaldo()));

        //Devolver al ListView la fila creada
        return convertView;

    }
}

public class AsyncGrabarCXCP extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Integer>
{
    int Recurso;
    Double Importe, Descuento, SubTotal, Total, Saldo;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog=new ProgressDialog(Detalle_Cliente.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Procesando Datos...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Recurso=webService.ObtenerRecurso();
            String Folio = webService.ObtenerFolio(35);
            Date O_D = new Date();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
            super.onPostExecute(integer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: deseas que por ejemplo todos los valores del TextView saldo en tu listado sean sumados?

Comment: ya quedo, gracias.... lo que queria era recorrer mi lista y ver los edittext y que los que tuvieran ingresado un valor los sumara

Comment: Hugo sería bueno agregaras tu solución para que otros usuarios vean lo que realizaste! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas maneras pero la que más te recomiendo yo es crear un ArrayList (ArrayClientes) global.

Este ArrayList debe ser introducido en el Adapter de listview pero debes hacer referencia

```
ArrayList<DetalleCxP> ArrayClientes;
public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DetalleCxP> ArrayClientes) {
    super(context, 0, ArrayClientes);
    this.ArrayClientes = ArrayClientes;
}
```

Y en el getView algo así;

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Esto en lugar del getItem(position);
        DetalleCxP O_DetalleCxP = ArrayClientes.get(position);
        //Tu código sigue igual
...
```

Ahora recuerda que el ArrayClientes debes pasarlo desde el onCreate para cuando presiones el botón los cambios sean guardados en el ArrayList y debes poner un valor en tu clase de "DetalleCxP" que haga referencia al editext, con esto (aunque suene extraño) pasará lo siguiente

```
ArrayClientes.get(position).editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono);
```

Ahora en el onCreate cuando des click en el botón recorres el arrayList uno por uno y pones lo siguiente por ejemplo:

```
for (int x = 0; x < ArrayClientes.length; x++) {
    String valor = ArrayClientes.get(position).editText.getText().toString();
    //Lo que quieras hacer con el valor...
}
```

Esto es programación orientada a objetos y referencia de objetos :D, suerte

PD. Recuerda que en tu clase DetalleCxP debes agregar un atributo EditText editText; suponiendo que quieres que funcione como lo puse, ponlo publico, si lo pones privado haz su setter y getter